# Multithreaded cached disk write throughput: strong variation per thread

Tags: linux, multithreading, caching, throughput, dd

When I submit 10 dd commands in parallel, 2 get 500 MB/s throughput, the other 8 get 200MB/s.

This does not only occur at 10 parallel dd's, this variation starts to become significant at around 8 dd's in parallel and stops at around 18, see box plot [here](http://oi58.tinypic.com/95rkh2.jpg).

When I test this without disk caching using oflags=direct, the variation is gone, all threads perform almost exactly the same.

vm.dirty-background-ratio = 50 so with 128 GB * 50% = 64 GB, the Dirty threshold has not been hit and writeback is not occurring.
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000 and 30 seconds has not been hit either.

What is causing this variation? And how can I ged rid of it?

This is a 32 core RHEL6 64-bit system with 128GB memory and ext4 formatted disks.
This behavior is repeatable, also on another RHEL box that I have.

The command I use to test this is:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/fs1/aaa$j bs=256k count=5000
```

The complete script i used for testing is:

```
outfile=./dd-${HOSTNAME}-$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S').dat
for fs in '/data/tmp'; do
  for i in `seq -w 1 20`; do
    rm $fs/aaa* 2>/dev/null
    for j in `seq -w 1 $i`; do
      { echo `date +'%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S'` $fs $i $j; time dd if=/dev/zero of=$fs/aaa$j bs=256k count=5000 ; } 2>&1 | paste -s -d " " | tr "\t" " " | tr -s " " >> $outfile &
    done
    wait
    rm $fs/aaa* 2>/dev/null
  done
done
```

which generates the follow output: for the 10 threads in parallel:

```
16Aug14:21:45:52 /data/tmp 10 01 5000+0 records in 5000+0 records out 1310720000 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 1.94452 s, 674 MB/s real 0m1.946s user 0m0.005s sys 0m1.939s
16Aug14:21:45:52 /data/tmp 10 10 5000+0 records in 5000+0 records out 1310720000 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 2.33119 s, 562 MB/s real 0m2.332s user 0m0.000s sys 0m2.331s
16Aug14:21:45:52 /data/tmp 10 09 5000+0 records in 5000+0 records out 1310720000 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 6.56941 s, 200 MB/s real 0m6.570s user 0m0.003s sys 0m5.528s
16Aug14:21:45:52 /data/tmp 10 03 5000+0 records in 5000+0 records out 1310720000 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 6.61216 s, 198 MB/s real 0m6.614s user 0m0.002s sys 0m5.745s
16Aug14:21:45:52 /data/tmp 10 02 5000+0 records in 5000+0 records out 1310720000 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 6.62207 s, 198 MB/s real 0m6.623s user 0m0.005s sys 0m5.574s
16Aug14:21:45:52 /data/tmp 10 04 5000+0 records in 5000+0 records out 1310720000 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 6.63135 s, 198 MB/s real 0m6.632s user 0m0.004s sys 0m5.574s
16Aug14:21:45:52 /data/tmp 10 05 5000+0 records in 5000+0 records out 1310720000 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 6.63068 s, 198 MB/s real 0m6.632s user 0m0.005s sys 0m5.756s
16Aug14:21:45:52 /data/tmp 10 07 5000+0 records in 5000+0 records out 1310720000 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 6.6317 s, 198 MB/s real 0m6.633s user 0m0.006s sys 0m5.587s
16Aug14:21:45:52 /data/tmp 10 06 5000+0 records in 5000+0 records out 1310720000 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 6.63953 s, 197 MB/s real 0m6.641s user 0m0.006s sys 0m5.769s
16Aug14:21:45:52 /data/tmp 10 08 5000+0 records in 5000+0 records out 1310720000 bytes (1.3 GB) copied, 6.65992 s, 197 MB/s real 0m6.662s user 0m0.005s sys 0m5.739s
```

thanks, Bart